# Is there a method to protect a port from a google cloud website / instance ith an Google Authentification Service?

Tags: security, authentication, nginx, google-cloud-platform, port

Is there a method to secure a port opened in Firewall with a Google Service instead of Nginx Authentification for example?

Comment: Secure, in which manner ? Do you want to block public Access or only access from specific IP ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I want to secure public access. Something like basic auth woud be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PORT is insecure when it is open and allowed public access, and if you are using google cloud platform, you can configure firewall rules in VPC, which means if you closed a port on VPC firewall this will be not accessible even if it is open in your virtual machine

If you want to block all public traffic to your virtual machine on specific port or all port  you can do it by configure Google VPC firewall rules. You can also allow traffic from only specific IP addresses which will allow you to access from specified internet but not from everywhere. For more details [read this.](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

Comment: Google recommend to not trust the network (i.e. the IP of the originator). Prefer software protection (OAuth, cookies, and other type of security)